# Correct way to create ImageDataGenerator from array with binary labels?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to train my first Tensorflow model based on a self-created dataset. The model is meant to recognize the gender of a person in photos, and I have 9231 gender-labeled photos of people prepared. (I use binary genders for this, enby and genderfluid pictures are hard to come by.)

To begin, the pictures are loaded into numpy array `features` with shape `(9231, 216, 172, 3)`, and the gender-labels are loaded into `labels` with shape `(9231, 2)`.

```py
# Divide into multiple datasets
training_size = int(len(features) * .8)
validation_size = int(len(features) * .1)
testing_size = int(len(features) * .1)
features_train = np.array(features[:training_size])
labels_train = np.array(labels[:training_size])
features_validation = np.array(features[training_size:training_size+validation_size])
labels_validation = np.array(labels[training_size:training_size+validation_size])
features_testing = np.array(features[training_size+validation_size:])
labels_testing = np.array(labels[training_size+validation_size:])
# Create two image generators, one for training and one for validation
img_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255
)
generator_training = img_gen.flow(
    x=features_train,
    y=labels_train,
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True
)
generator_validation = img_gen.flow(
    x=features_validation,
    y=labels_validation,
    batch_size=32
)
# Check format of resulting generated data
print(generator_training[0][0].shape)
print(generator_training[0][1].shape)
print(generator_validation[0][0].shape)
print(generator_validation[0][1].shape)
print(generator_training.dtype)
print(generator_validation.dtype)
```

This prints what I expect:

```
(32, 216, 172, 3)
(32, 2)
(32, 216, 172, 3)
(32, 2)
float32
float32
```

Then I build the model, copied from a dog-cat tutorial:

```py
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(172, 216, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.fit(
    generator_training,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=generator_validation,
)
```

This results in `model.fit()` throwing the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,2] and labels shape [64]
```

I don't know what "logits" are or what part in the ML process they come into play, so I don't really know how to troubleshoot this error. But from the resulting shapes, it seems like the label array were incorrectly flattened at some point. My guess is that I created the generators incorrectly, or misformatted the labels before that.

I have a hint about what's wrong though: The tutorial I copied code from used `flow_from_directory()` to create the generators, with allowed for the additional argument `class_mode` which was set to `'binary'`. But since I use arrays instead of file directories, I instead used `flow()` which doesn't allow for `class_mode`. My gut feeling says this is where the problem stems from. But the actual effect of the argument and its options was never explained in the tutorial.

Unfortunately I cannot test `flow_from_directory()` instead, due to the structure of the rest of the program. I don’t really want to approach this without generator either, since I wanna try image augmentation later.

Answer (score 1):

You use the labels in an unsuitable form for the `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` loss function. The latter expects the labels to be in the form `[0,1,2,3...n)`. However, your logits are of the form `(32,2)`.

A solution would be to change the loss function to `categorical_crossentropy`, so that labels such as `[0,1]` (class 1) and `[1,0]` (class 2) can be correctly fed to the model.

If you had used `flow_from_directory()`, you could have used the argument `class_mode = 'sparse'` which would have worked used in conjunction with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.